# How to set ssh keys in cloud-init?

Tags: ssh, 22.04, cloud-init

I am using cloud-init to set up a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Server 22.04.1.  I would like to set the device's SSH keys so I can connect without being vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack.

My current user-data is:

```yaml
#cloud-config
users:
- name: 'foo'
  groups: users,adm,dialout,audio,netdev,video,plugdev,cdrom,games,input,gpio,spi,i2c,render,sudo
  shell: /bin/bash
  lock_passwd: true
  ssh_authorized_keys:
    - 'ssh-ed25519 ...'
  ssh_keys:
    ed25519_private: |
      -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
      ...
      -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
    ed25519_public: ...
```

When I go to ssh into the device, its ECDSA fingerprint changes every time.  (i.e. if I re-image the drive and let cloud-init run again, then go SSH in, the fingerprint is different. It never matches the fingerprint of the keys in `ed25519_private/public` from the user-data.)  So I think it's generating new keys on boot, and I'm at a loss for how to stop that.

How can I set the device's SSH keys?

**Update (per @muru):**

The host key section of the cloud-init [docs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#host-keys) includes a few relevant entries:

- Theoretically if you specify `ssh_keys` then no new keys will be generated.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong that this is not the case.
- I've tried putting `ssh_deletekeys: false` under `ssh_keys`, the user object, and at the global level.  SSH'ing in still produces new key fingerprints each time.
- I've tried putting `ssh_genkeytypes: []` under `ssh_keys`, the user object, and at the global level.  Sometimes (I didn't record which) this results in me being unable to ssh in at all, presumably because no keys are present.  In no case did I see the correct key fingerprint (as derived from ed25519_private).
- Some entries let me import public keys to my authorized keys, publish keys, suppress keygen output or enable/disable root login.  I'm not interested in any of those things.
- `ssh_keys` is the only section that claims to let me set the private keys of the host
- No other entry in this section seems to let me control whether keys are generated, or specify private host keys to use.  Maybe I'm misreading something?

Lastly, I just did an `ssh-keyscan <host> | ssh-keygen -lf -` and saw that, apparently, my device is generating an ECDSA key in addition to an ed25519 key:

```
$ ssh-keyscan <host> | ssh-keygen -lf -
# <host>:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
# <host>:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
# <host>:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
256 SHA256:T50YAWwIgIOsQNuIXGBpoz1xPFXJkzffafibruuABtQ <host> (ECDSA)
256 SHA256:DB00DS6xzx5v7ZdVBe+z4nLZhOGVrKuSdhwdenhAm4s <host> (ED25519)
```

(neither signature matches the signature of `ed25519_private`)

Comment: You need to set the *host keys*: https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#host-keys

Comment: @muru Don't worry, I looked at the docs before asking =)  Issue is, I can't figure out how to make it work - I've tried every vaguely-relevant option in that section in every way I can think of, but none of them make this work.  Since re-reading the docs a few times didn't help, I asked here.

Comment: Can you show *how* exactly you tried that section?

Comment: @muru does that help?

Comment: No, you need to show the cloud-init config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately the answer had three parts:

1. `ssh_keys:` needed to be at the top level, not under a user
2. `ssh_deletekeys: false` needed to be at the top level, not under `ssh_keys:`
3. YAML multiline string syntax is very delicate.  I'm still not sure what exactly I was doing wrong there, but I switched to using double-quote syntax with a trailing `\n` and it started working.

The final user-data definition is as follows:

```yaml
#cloud-config
users:
- name: 'foo'
  groups: users,adm,dialout,audio,netdev,video,plugdev,cdrom,games,input,gpio,spi,i2c,render,sudo
  shell: /bin/bash
  lock_passwd: true
  ssh_authorized_keys:
    - 'ssh-ed25519 ...'

ssh_keys:
  ed25519_private: "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
  ed25519_public: ...

ssh_deletekeys: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're referring to the host keys in this scenario.

To fix host keys getting overwritten, set

```
ssh_deletekeys: false
```

By default, cloud-init will overwrite existing host keys every time it detects that it is running on a new instance. This is the default behavior for security purposes. In a cloud environment, a common use case is to create new images from existing instances. In that scenario, launching new instances but keeping existing host keys from the previous instance would be a security vulnerability.

For a physical device like a Raspberry Pi, this use case shouldn't be relevant, so you can set `ssh_deletekeys` to `false`.

Comment: I've tried putting `ssh_deletekeys: false` under `ssh_keys` (and also tried it separately under the user object), but the keys are still getting regenerated.  Is there something additional required to make this work?